# Moved Wordpress site from Linux host to IIS7 - Home page works, everything else returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress, iis-7, windows-server-2008

The title sums it up nicely but yes, after migrating a Wordpress site from my Dreamhost server to personal Windows VPS running IIS7, everything outside of the home page is being treated as a REAL directory (i.e. homepage.com/about) and not a virtual one and so the server returns a 404 - File or directory not found.

What do I need to do to tell IIS this is mostly a dynamic site and not static.

Comment: If I had to guess, settings within IIS (such as those for url-rewrites), were not copied over. Are you using `.htaccess` or `apache/httpd.conf`?

Comment: Search for *iis wordpress seo urls* on Google. First link: http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/installing-wordpress-on-iis7-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the URL Rewriting extension: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

You'll need to convert your rules from Apache's `mod_rewrite` format to IIS's regular expressions, if you're using PHP's `PATH_INFO` then this is easy.

Comment: Installing url-rewrite and making the requisite mods to web.config per the link above did the trick.  Thanks fellas.